# CALayer scale not affected by frame?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, uiimage, calayer

I'm adding a sublayer with contents of a CGImage. I create it's frame, which i thought included it's bounds and position. I also set the layers contentsGravity, so the image would resize properly in the UIImageView, but the imageview only shows part of the image, indicating that the CALayer didn't scale the image properly. What's really going on here? Why doesn't the CALayer have the right scale?

```
-(void)setImageInView:(UIImage*)img {
    CALayer *mosaicLayer = [CALayer layer];

    mosaicLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f, 720.0f, 960.0f);
    mosaicLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
    mosaicLayer.contents = (id)[img CGImage];

    [imageView.layer addSublayer:mosaicLayer];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mosaicLayer.bounds.size);
    [mosaicLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *saver = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saver, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);   }
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you expect to happen and what does happen? Screenshots would help. What is the frame and bounds of the imageView?

Comment: I solved all of this by making UIImageViews instead of CALayers. I needed those anyway, so i could add gesturerecognizers, which seemingly isn't allowed on CALayers.. Thanks anyway..

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer so we can select this answer and close the question? Thanks.

Comment: Too localized?  Give me a break.  Maybe you trigger-happy moderators should go get some fresh air and let a question's utility be decided over time, by votes and views…  (5 votes, 700 views as of this writing).  Hardly worth badgering the OP to act in X, Y, or Z way just so it can be closed.  This is a Q&A site, not an abortion clinic!